# How do I allow ContinuousIntegration.exe to use a connection string in Azure Key Vault

Tags: kentico, azure-keyvault

I've got a Kentico Xperience (v13) instance in Azure and I want to run `ContinuousIntegration.exe` to populate my database up there with content from my CI xml files.  The catch is that we're injecting the `CMSConnectionString` setting into the web app from Azure Key Vault (AKV) and the CI.exe isn't seeing it.  Instead I get this error message:

```
CMS.DataEngine.ApplicationInitException: Cannot access the database specified by the 'CMSConnectionString' connection string. Please install the database externally and set a correct connection string.
```

Or maybe this error message:

```
Failed to execute the command.
```

Here's the relevant section from our web.config (that works for the website!):

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <!--Should be provided by Azure Key Vault-->
</connectionStrings>
```

How do I ensure that the executable gets access to the secrets in AKV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to let **ContinuousIntegration.exe** know about a secure connection string with a small custom module that sets the connection string at startup. Here is the basic code of the module:

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyDiscoverable]
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(AzureConnectionStringModule))]

public class AzureConnectionStringModule : Module
{
    public AzureConnectionStringModule()
        : base(nameof(AzureConnectionStringModule))
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPreInit()
    {
        base.OnPreInit();

        var azureConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_CMSConnectionString");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureConnectionString))
        {
            azureConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CMSConnectionString");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureConnectionString))
        {
            SettingsHelper.ConnectionStrings.SetConnectionString("CMSConnectionString", azureConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

From a fresh installation of Kentico Xperience 13, here are steps to configure this:

1. Follow the steps here to add Key Vault support to the admin app locally: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service.
2. Add the module above to the solution in a class library. Make sure the main project references the class library so that it is included during building.
3. Ensure that the *~\web.config* does not have a connection string, or an app setting, named **CMSConnectionString**.
4. Deploy the app to an App Service.
5. In Azure, create an App Service configuration setting with name **CMSConnectionString** and value *@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=your-keyvault;SecretName=CMSConnectionString)*.
6. In the Key Vault, create a secret with name **CMSConnectionString** and value a connection string to an Azure SQL database. You may also need to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references to create an access policy for my App Service.
7. At this point, the Kentico Xperience 13 admin should load with access to the database.
8. In the App Service portal, under **Development Tools** select **Console**.
9. In the console, run `cd bin` and then `ContinuousIntegration.exe -r`. This should produce a message about the repository not being configured, or output on the restore action.

Comment: I couldn't do step #1 above where you use AKV for local development. My account doesn't have permissions.  The rest of it seemed to work so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I made this code into Kentico Module so it is easy to add to existing Kentico project.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/KenticoCommunity.ConnectionStringModule/0.0.1